# Bash Script for Automation - Command not found

Tags: bash, sh

I have the following in my .bash_profile:

```
k9 () { for A in $(ps -A | grep $* | sed 's/^\([A-Za-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' ; ) ; do "kill -9  $A"; done  }
```

The script supposed to grep the var inputed in the command line S* get the PIDs those and execute a kill -9 on each of them. But instead I am getting this:

```
Machine:~ mach$ k1 Chromium
-bash: kill -9  81922: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82009: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82423: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82424: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82560: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82561: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82563: command not found
-bash: kill -9  82608: command not found
-bash: kill -9  85243: command not found
-bash: kill -9  85248: command not found
-bash: kill -9  85321: command not found
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider breaking the script up into multiple lines to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to quote the entire command.

```
k9 () {
  for A in $(ps -A | grep $* | sed 's/^\([A-Za-z0-9]*\).*/\1/' ; ) ; do
    kill -9  "$A"
  done
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks chepner!